# Static application scope datastore VS passing data per bundles

Tags: android, android-fragments

I wonder about following, maybe someone can clear that up for me:

I am having an application which loads some json feeds initially on application start.
This data is needed in each fragment, and the standard way for me would be to retrieve it in the MainActivity and to pass it in bundles to my fragments.
Downside: Serialisation, complicated Datasync, lots of bundling and unbundling code.

What about just putting the data in some global, static DataSource class and accessing it from the fragments/activities? Would be super simple - however, it seems to have a drawback:
When fragments are resumed after the app stayed in the background for a while, it seems that all global static data is lost.
How would you handle such a usecase? Is there a way to persist and reload static data without having to map everything and store it into a DB?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I am having an application which loads some json feeds initially on application start.

Nobody has universal, perpetual connectivity. Hence, you need a persistence strategy to deal with the cases where the user wants to use your app but is unable to connect to the server, for whatever reason.

> When fragments are resumed after the app stayed in the background for a while, it seems that all global static data is lost.

That is because your process was terminated, and your JSON is not part of your saved instance state. Large model data, like your JSON, usually is not something you want as part of your saved instance state anyway.

> How would you handle such a usecase?

Use a file or database on internal storage as a backing store. Static data members are *only* a cache for such a persistent store, nothing more.

> Is there a way to persist and reload static data without having to map everything and store it into a DB?

You already have the JSON. Write it to a file, if nothing else.

As noted earlier in my answer, you need to have a plan in mind for dealing with a lack of connectivity or other reasons why these feeds cannot be retrieved. That should tie into your persistence strategy. The Internet updates your persistent store (and, along the way, updates any in-memory caches).

Comment: Thanks, good explanation. Even though there are tons apps which don't work offline at all- so this is not the issue here IMO..